# Overview of available octopress variables for theming?

Tags: api, jekyll, liquid, octopress

I would like to create my own design for Octopress. Until now i figured out how Jekyll and Liquid are working and I think I'm ready to start. When looking in the classic theme I can see everywhere variables like `paginator.posts` and I was wondering if there is an overview of all available variables. But I wasn't able to find one. Can you giv me any resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Octopress is based on [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/), so you can refer to the [Template Data](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Template-Data) entry on the Jekyll Wiki.